# Is there a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $x \in (\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)^{'}$ but for all $k \in \mathbb{N}, x \notin A_k^{'}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

Does a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ exist where $x \in (\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k)^{'}$ however for all $k \in \mathbb{N}, x \notin A_k^{'}$.

(I'm using $A^{'}$ to indicate the set of accumulation (cluster) points.}

If for every $r > 0$ we let $A_r = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| < \frac{1}{r}\}$ Doesn't this satisfy the subset sequence?  Since the infinite union would include $r=1$ we can create an open ball at x that doesn't include the element x but intersects with $A_r$ like so $B(x,1) \bigcup (A_r \setminus \{x\}) \not = \emptyset$ which is the definition of an accumulation (cluster) point.  However we know that the element x is not in $A_r^{'}$ since the infinite intersection of the individual sets does not satisfy the Finite Intersection Property and the infinite intersection of $A_k^{'} = \emptyset$ for all $r>0$.

Comment: Let $n=1$ and $A_k=\{1/k\}$. Then $0$ is an accumulation point of the union of the $A_k$'s but not of any single $A_k$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm close to conceptualizing this.  Still at that point where I fight with the notation at times.  How does the n=1 figure into your answer?  Do you mean n=1 in the sense that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ i.e.  $\mathbb{R}^{1}?

Comment: Yes, my $n$ is the $n$ from your question, the dimension of the space under consideration.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So basically what you are implying is that my train of thought was correct...excellent.

Comment: You've gone from a sequence $A_k$ to a continuously indexed $A_r.$ Weird.  The union of all $A_r$ is all of $\mathbb R^n.$ I can't tell what you are doing.

Comment: @zhw $A_k$ is the set of of Accumulation points.